# argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' typescript solution

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I am getting an error here for newUser `this.userObj.assigned_to.push(newUser);` as `argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' typescript solution`

How do I declare newUser to get rid of error?

Thank you for your help.

```
addSubData(user: any) {
    let i: any;
    i = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    for(var checked of i) {
      const newUser = Object.assign({}, user)
      newUser.dl = checked.value;
      newUser.sub_impact = "Applicable";
      newUser.co_score = "Added";
      this.userObj.assigned_to.push(newUser);
    }
    this.commonService.updateUser(this.userObj).subscribe(()=> {
      this.getLatestUser();
    });
  }
```

Comment: It seems like there is an incompatibility with the definition of `userObj` or `userObj.assigned_to`. Can you please include the code where you define the interface and initialize the code?

Comment: @PMO1948 please refer to this url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8j9ez9?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

You code looks like to miss out defining enough typings so it's pretty hard to provide you a best way to fix (obviously the best way is to fill out the type for things you have defined such as class members).

Anyway the error here is somehow array of `assigned_to` has to be passed `never` type as each member type but now you're passing `any` type.

#### A temporary fix

You can cast `newUser` of `any` type to `never` type would fix the issue:

```js
this.userObj.assigned_to.push(newUser as never);
```

Comment: I am getting on so many places :( Property does not exist on type 'never'.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
assigned_to: [];
```

To

```
assigned_to = [];
```